# Prove for entropy of a binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory

I am trying to prove the following identity for a Binomial $(n,p)$ random variable $X$,

$$
H(X)= n h_2(p) + \mathbb{E}{n \choose X}
$$

I've started with the definition of entropy but I am unable to juggle the terms appropriately to reach the above identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $P(X=i)=\binom n i p^i (1-p)^{n-i}$. So 
$$ H(X) = -\sum_{i=0}^n P(X=i)\lg P(X=i)$$ 
$$ = -\sum_{i=0}^n \binom n i p^i (1-p)^{n-i}\left(\lg \binom n i+i\lg p+(n-i)\lg(n-i)\right).$$
Now let's look at each term:
$$-\sum_{i=0}^n \binom n i p^i (1-p)^{n-i}\lg \binom n i=-E\lg\binom nX,$$
$$-\sum_{i=0}^n \binom n i p^i (1-p)^{n-i} i\lg p=-\lg p EX=-np\lg p,$$
$$-\sum_{i=0}^n \binom n i p^i (1-p)^{n-i} (n-i)\lg (1-p)=-\lg (1-p) E(n-X)=-n(1-p)\lg (1-p).$$

So we have 
$$H(X)=n h_2(p)-E\lg\binom nX.$$

Comment: Got it. Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome.